# VBScript Copy and BITS. When does it end?

Tags: vbscript, copy, microsoft-bits

So I have a VBScript to copy a folder. What I noticed, because I'm doing time trials, is the copy seems to continue in the background after the script ends.

I think what is happening is, when the last file to be copied has started, the script exists... not when the last file has finished copying.

I think this is caused by the BITS service in Windows. If I want accurate time trials, what do I need to disable, or write, to ensure the time trial is from beginning to end?

This is what I have

```
Sub CopyDirs( fromFolder, toFolder )
 Dim oFSO
 Dim c_folder, c_File, subFolder
 Set oFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
 Set c_folder = oFSO.GetFolder( fromFolder )
 If Not( oFSO.FolderExists( toFolder ) ) Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder toFolder
 End If
 For Each c_File In c_folder.Files
  If Not( oFSO.FileExists( toFolder & "\" & c_File.Name ) ) Then
   oFSO.CopyFile c_folder.Path & "\" & c_File.Name, toFolder & "\" & c_File.Name
  End If
 Next
 For Each subFolder In c_folder.SubFolders
  If Not( oFSO.FolderExists( toFolder & "\" & subFolder.Name ) ) Then
   oFSO.CreateFolder toFolder & "\" & subFolder.Name
  End If
  CopyDirs subFolder.Path, toFolder & "\" & subFolder.Name
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

File writes are cached.

Right click the Drive - Properties - Hardware tab - select your drive and click Properties button, then the Policies tab and clear checkboxes.

BITS download files from the internet, such as Windows Updates, in the background.

Comment: Well shoot. That wasn't even on my radar. I don't think I can control the cache on the server end... maybe I should write the smallest files last?